# ruby -v is correct but bundler thinks older version in play

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

Getting the `your ruby version is 2.3.1 but your Gemfile specified 2.4.5` error.

The application is running fine until it has to generate a PDF via the wkhtmltopdf process and then hits this error. The other valid elements of error state that definition.rb, bundler.rb and setup.rb  are within the `user_two`'s directory `.rbenv/versions/2.4.5`, while   `kernel_require.rb:55:in require` is within a path of

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems[...]
```

Gemfile does in fact specify `RUBY VERSION ruby 2.4.5p335 BUNDLED WITH 1.17.2`  while `ruby -v` returns

```
ruby 2.4.5p335 (2018-10-18 revision 65137) [x86_64-linux]
```

/usr/bin/  has interesting directories. `gem   gem2.3 ruby ruby2.3`

Note: there is another user `deploy` that was created before this user and upon which ruby and rbenv was installed.

```
rbenv install 2.4.5
rbenv local 2.4.5 
rbenv rehash
```

does not change this behaviour.

```
$ env | grep PATH
PATH=/home/user_two/bin:/home/user_two/.local/bin:/home/user_two/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/user_two/.rbenv/shims:/home/user_two/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

How can I get this application fully in synch with the proper ruby version?

Comment: Which commands you are using for running your app? Is it a rails app or vanila ruby scripts? Did you tried prepending your command with `bundle exec`?

Comment: It is a rails application.  The command is a call to Mailer, which encompasses a PDF generation.  Note: `bundle exec` should not be an element of solution, as the application runs well on another(production) server.